# Sending mail when test fails in Selenium IDE?

Tags: email, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I have big website with many registered users and I need to create a looped test with automatically log-in and log-out my test user (one time per hour). It's very easy in Selenium IDE. But next thing is sending an email when logging in will not work. And I don't know how I have to do this. Can Selenium IDE send me an email after every unsuccessful log-in attempt in that test?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a continuous integration tool for that type of thing. Check out [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) which is easy to install. Then within Jenkins you create a job that launch your Selenium IDE test (probably through a BATCH or SHELL script). And within this Jenkins job, you can configure to receive an email in case of failure.

Once you have this Jenkins CI in place, you will be able to use it to launch all sort of jobs. Not only the test, but also the build and other engineering automated tasks. That's become the backbone of your Engineering organisation along with your SCM and Issue Tracker.

Comment: I disagree. The seleniumIDE can't do this.  This is done with WebDriver.  The difference is huge to newer or non-programmers.

Answer (score 0):

As Laurent Said you can use Jenkins to email you when tests fail but you will have to use [Seleniumhq](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Seleniumhq+Plugin) instead of Selenium-ide.

The good news is that you can still write your tests in selenium-ide and then transfer them across to seleniumhq and let Jenkins take it from there.